# opendkim command is not working with PHP

Tags: php, linux

I am running this command `opendkim-genkey --domain=example.com --selector=example --subdomains` on Linux terminal, It is working properly, but when I try to run this in my PHP page like 
`shell_exec("opendkim-genkey --domain=example.com --selector=example --subdomains");`
this is not working..
I also try to run another command in my php page, and I get result of them.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Thank You. @Pierre-JeanBergeron, Your answer was vary helpful for me, Actually I am new on Stack Overflow so I am unable to vote you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see three explanations:

- `opendkim-genkey` is not found because the environment variables are not the same: use an absolute path
- Your Apache (or other webserver) user does not have permission to execute this command: you can use sudo, see https://serverfault.com/questions/157272/allow-apache-to-run-a-command-as-a-different-user
- And as [@rups](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2481010/rups) suggested, your user may need write permission (if `opendkim-genkey` generates a key file)

Comment: Ya Your are right. One possible reason would be Opendkim-genkey will generate key file for that need write permission on Web document directory